# Trouble gathering Scanner data

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, polymorphism

QUESTION: How do I gather all the information a user enters, store them into an ArrayList and
 display all of the inputted answers? I'm supposed to enter six teams names, wins, division, etc and display them into a table with System.out.println(); as I have attempted at the end of my for-loop

```
public class PlayoffSelectorClass extends Team {

// main method
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Team team1 = new Team();
       Team team2 = new Team();
       Team team3 = new Team();
       Team team4 = new Team();
       Team team5 = new Team();
       Team team6 = new Team();

       for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

           System.out.println("Please enter team name: ");
           String name = input.nextLine();

           System.out.println("\nPlease enter the city " + name + " played in: ");
           String city = input.nextLine();

           System.out.println("\nPlease enter the division " + name + " play in: ");
           String division = input.nextLine();

           System.out.println("\nPlease enter the number of wins " + name + " has: ");
           Integer wins = input.nextInt();

           System.out.println("\nPlease enter the number of losses " + name + " has: ");
           Integer loses = input.nextInt();

           if (i < 5) {
               System.out.println("\nEnter your next team...\n");
           }

           team1.setTeamName(name);
           team1.setCity(city);
           team1.setDivision(division);
           team1.setWins(wins);
           team1.setLoses(loses);

       }

       System.out.println("East   W   L   PCT");

       System.out.println(team1.getTeamName() + " " + team1.getWins() + " " + team1.getLoses());
    System.out.println(team1.getTeamName() + " " + team1.getWins() + " " + team1.getLoses());


   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If ur sure that the number of teams u want is 6 then declare an array like

```
List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();
```

This should be a design change and you shudnt keep Team1, Team2...etc.

And when u want to save data then

```
Team team = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
team = new Team();
System.out.println("Please enter team name: ");
String teamName = input.nextLine();
team.setTeamName(teamName);
... // Similarly the rest. 
teams.add(team);
```

Also some additional checks when ur taking input from the console. Check to see whether its a blank string or just an enter. These checks will make the code more error free.

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly declare a variable for each player, you will have a hard time storing a user's input into the correct variable (unless you do some nasty stuff like `if(i==3) team3.setName(name)`). Better create an array list (`List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>`) and in each loop create a new `Team` object (`Team team = new Team();`) that you are going to fill (`team.setName(name)`, etc.). At the end of each iteration, this object will be added to your array list (`teams.add(team)`). After all six iterations you will have an array list that contains each team the user created. Now you can iterate through this list by:

```
for(Team team: teams) {
  //do stuff with the team object, e.g.:
  System.out.println(team.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use List like this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PlayoffSelector {

    static class Team {
        private String teamName;
        private String city;
        private String division;
        private Integer wins;
        private Integer loses;

        public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
            this.teamName = teamName;
        }

        public String getTeamName() {
            return teamName;
        }

        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
        }

        public String getCity() {
            return city;
        }

        public void setDivision(String division) {
            this.division = division;
        }

        public String getDivision() {
            return division;
        }

        public void setWins(Integer wins) {
            this.wins = wins;
        }

        public Integer getWins() {
            return wins;
        }

        public void setLoses(Integer loses) {
            this.loses = loses;
        }

        public Integer getLoses() {
            return loses;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Team> teams  = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Please enter team name: ");
            String name = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("\nPlease enter the city " + name + " played in: ");
            String city = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("\nPlease enter the division " + name + " play in: ");
            String division = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("\nPlease enter the number of wins " + name + " has: ");
            Integer wins = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("\nPlease enter the number of losses " + name + " has: ");
            Integer loses = input.nextInt();

            if (i < 5) {
                System.out.println("\nEnter your next team...\n");
            }

            Team team = new Team();
            team.setTeamName(name);
            team.setCity(city);
            team.setDivision(division);
            team.setWins(wins);
            team.setLoses(loses);

            teams.add(team);

        }

        System.out.println("East W   L   PCT");

        for (Team team : teams) {
            System.out.printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n",team.getTeamName(), team.getWins() , team.getLoses());
        }

    }
}
```